# Expand $\ln{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}$ around $0$ with remainder term of the form $O(x^8)$.

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm having huge troubles with problems like this. I know the following:

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^7)$$

and

$$\ln{(1+t)}=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+O(t^4)$$

So

$$\ln{\left(1+\left(-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^7)\right)\right)}=\\\left[-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^7)\right]-\frac{\left[-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^7)\right]^2}{2}+\frac{\left[-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^7)\right]^3}{3}+O(x^8).$$

But how on earth would one simplify this? Obviously I should not need to manually expand something of the form $(a+b+c+d+e)^n$. Seriously don't understand what is happening here.

Also, how should I know to what $O(x^?)$ I should expand the initial functions to?

Comment: You only need to expand a few terms, depending on your preferred order of accuracy

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a series expansion up to $x^6$, then

$$ \left( -\frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!} + O(x^8)\right)^2 =  
\frac{x^4}{(3!)^2} - 2\frac{x^6}{3!5!} + O(x^8) $$

$$ \left( -\frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{5!} - \frac{x^6}{7!} + O(x^8)\right)^3 = -\frac{x^6}{(3!)^3} + O(x^8) $$

The remaining higher-order terms are all grouped in with $O(x^8)$

Comment: Ok, it seems that it's time for me to learn Pascal's triangle now.

Comment: It's not so bad. The exponents get large fairly quickly, so you won't have to expand very far.

Comment: But in my last line I have $O(x^7)$, how did you get $O(x^8)$?

Comment: $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is an even function

Comment: Ah... the $x^7$ term is zero. So the next must be $x^8$.

Answer (score 2):

If
$f(x)
= \ln \sin(x)
$,
then
$f'(x)
=\dfrac{\sin'(x)}{\sin(x)}
=\dfrac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}
=\cot(x)
$.

From
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Series_definitions,
we have
$\cot(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}
=\dfrac1{x}-\dfrac{x}{3}-\dfrac{x^3}{45}-\dfrac{2x^5}{945}-...
$
where the
$B_{2n}$
are the Bernoulli numbers.

Integrating term-by-term,
and ignoring the constant,
$f(x)
=\ln(x)-\dfrac{x^2}{6}-\dfrac{x^4}{180}-\dfrac{x^6}{2835}-...
$.

So
$\ln\frac{\sin(x)}{x}
=\ln\sin(x)-\ln(x)
=-\dfrac{x^2}{6}-\dfrac{x^4}{180}-\dfrac{x^6}{2835}-...
$

To get the complete power series,

$\begin{array}\\
\ln \sin(x)
&= \int \cot(x) dx\\
&=\int \dfrac{dx}{x}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int dx\dfrac{(-1)^n2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}\\
&=\ln(x)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)(2n)!}\\
\text{so}\\
\ln (\sin(x)/x)
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^n2^{2n}B_{2n}x^{2n}}{(2n)(2n)!}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{x}=1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^8)$$

and

$$\ln{(1+t)}=t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{3}+O(t^4)$$

then substitute and expand keeping only the terms with order less than $x^8$ thus you don't need to expand all the expression but only the parts you need.

That is

$$\ln{\left(1+\left(-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^8)\right)\right)}
=\\\left[-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^8)\right]-\frac12\left[-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^8)\right]^2+\frac13\left[-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}+O(x^8)\right]^3+O(x^8)
=\\-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\frac{x^6}{7!}
-\frac12\frac{x^4}{(3!)^2}+\frac12\frac{2x^6}{3!5!}+\frac12\frac{x^8}{(5!)^2}-\frac13\frac{x^6}{(3!)^3}+O(x^8)$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin x}{x}=\prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right) \tag{1}$$
implies
$$ \log\frac{\sin x}{x} = -\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{x^{2m}}{m n^{2m}\pi^{2m}}=-\sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\zeta(2m)\,x^{2m}}{m\pi^{2m}} \tag{2}$$
and by recalling $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6},\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90},\zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$ we get
$$ \log\frac{\sin x}{x} = -\frac{x^2}{6}-\frac{x^4}{180}-\frac{x^6}{2835}+O(x^8).\tag{3}$$